# I'm attempting to only nest resources 1 level deep. How do I make a controller's index defn work for both routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, associations

I've got this working for the most part, but am getting stuck in one area.

So I've got this defined...

```
  resources :rooms do
    resources :visits, shallow: true
  end

  #resources :visits
```

Works great. I can get rooms/3/visits just like I want.

My visits_controller has...

```
    def index
        @visits = Room.find(params[:room_id]).visits.order('date')
        respond_with({visits: @visits}.as_json)          
    end
```

This is fine. However... if I want to be able to view all the visits... a la /visits, then my controller definition is going to break this, because the index definition wants a :room_id.

How do you define a controller's index to work both ways, both with an independent visit route and with a nested-resource route of one specific room?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to to probably brute force it:

```
def index
    @visits = if params[:room_id]
        Room.find(params[:room_id]).visits
    else
        Visit.all
    end.order('date')

    respond_with({visits: @visits}.as_json)         
end
```

If you wanted to tidy this up a little bit

```
def index
    @visits = collection.order('date')
    respond_with({visits: @visits}.as_json)
end

def collection
    if params[:room_id]
        Room.find(params[:room_id]).visits
    else
        Visit.all
    end
end
```

Then your routes would be:

```
resources :rooms do
    resources :visits, shallow: true
end

resources :visits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named route for just `visits#index` action like this:

```
get '/visits', to: 'visits#index'

resources :rooms do
   resources :visits, shallow: true
end
```

Now you have two routes pointing to `visits#index`. One that's nested inside `:rooms` and one that's independent: `/visits`

Comment: I added another answer due to this one using the hardcoded route... if you wanted more actions on visits then you quickly will have a really bad routes file.